# how to make analog clock invisible and visible on click button android

Tags: android

i working in app and want to invisible and visible the analog clock when i click on buttons

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<AnalogClock
    android:id="@+id/AnalogClock"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/show"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="show" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/hide"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hide" />
```

here is the code that i used but its not working

```
      final    AnalogClock clock =(AnalogClock) findViewById(R.id.AnalogClock);
        Button show= (Button) findViewById(R.id.show);
             Button hide= (Button) findViewById(R.id.hide);


          show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    clock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

    });
             hide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    clock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

    });
```

i trying to click on buttons but there is no actions so any one know how to make it works please ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      AnalogClock clock  = (AnalogClock) v; 
      clock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

this is wrong, v is your button, not the clock. you need to just do

```
clock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

---

**EDIT**
I've tested your code and it works:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            final AnalogClock clock = (AnalogClock) findViewById(R.id.AnalogClock);
            Button show = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show);
            Button hide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hide);

            show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    clock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
            hide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    clock.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

And the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <AnalogClock
        android:id="@+id/AnalogClock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/show"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="show" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hide" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i tried it but still visible when i click to hide it .. is there is any other solution ?