# TextClock in android is null

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm doing a view, where I need to put a TextClock, first it has to be in `visibility = gone` , and when user clicks in a checkbox , the visibility of the textclock has to change to visible.

The layout looks like that: (**activity_main_activity_2**)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <!-- Title -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editTitle"
            android:layout_weight="0.06"
            android:inputType="text" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Description -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/description"
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_weight="0.02"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editDescription"
            android:layout_weight="0.04"
            android:inputType="text" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Time -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/time_update">

        <TextClock
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/clock_important"
            android:textSize="25sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Important -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:text="@string/important"
            android:id="@+id/important"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Buttons -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <!-- Edit -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/edit"
            android:id="@+id/btn_edit"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_weight="0.05" />
        <!-- Cancel -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_weight="0.05" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, the id of the clock is:  `android:id="@+id/clock_important"`.

then in the activity I do:

```
TextClock clock;
......
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_2);

        clock = (TextClock) findViewById(R.id.clock_important);
        clock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ....
```

And here is where the problem comes, because `clock` is null.

[image]

**Log file**

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.dm.ejercicio_1.MainActivity_2.onCreate(MainActivity_2.java:40)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I solve it? I don't know why is not inflating it....

P.S: I set `minSdkVersion 17`

**EDIT 08/10/15 --> SOLUTION FOUND**

Finally I found the solution.
When I created the activity, Android Studio created a second layout, one for new version and the other for v17, and the id I used was different to the id that AS used for the v17 layout. That's the reason always was null.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**TextClock**  Change your xml like following

```
<android.widget.TextClock
android:id="@+id/textclock"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:timeZone="GMT+0800"
android:format24Hour="MMM dd, yyyy k:mm"
android:format12Hour="@null" />
```

Comment: Nope..is still crashing with NullPointer

Comment: i find solution ...actually problem is setVisibility(View.GONE);....refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645065/how-to-make-analog-clock-invisible-and-visible-on-click-button-android

Comment: actually the problem is similar, but not the same, because, the code never arrives to bind the widget to the object, that's why I'm getting the "null pointer" exception. It crash, becaus when I try to do clock.setVisibility(View.GONE) the object clock, is null

Comment: best try clean and run project

Comment: neither ...  is really strange :s

Comment: thanks for your efforts, finally I found the problem. I edited the question with it. Thanks!

Comment: @sa  I am getting null pointer exception which dialog dismiss `Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean 
android.os.Handler.postAtTime(java.lang.Runnable, 
long)' on a null object reference
android.widget.TextClock$2.run (TextClock.java:178)`